# New pool heater install wiring question

Tags: heater, pool

I am installing a raypak natural gas pool heater in my garage. It has dual voltage 120v or 240v. There was a pool heater in the garage at some point, previous home owner removed it. There is a Gfci outlet next to space where heater was, there are no other electrical connections in the area for a pool heater. My question is can I connect an electrical cord to the unit and plug it into the outlet or should I remove outlet and hardwire to supply in outlet box?

Comment: First step is to check the instructions. If it says one or the other that's what you must do. If it allows plug or hardwire then other factors come into consideration.

Comment: You wouldn't need to remove the outlet.  GFCI receptacles have 2 pairs of terminals you can tap (each screw can take 2 wires): "Line" which *does not* provide GFCI protection to the appliance, and "Load" which *does* provide GFCI protection. In a water-handling machine, the choice is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

The electronic ignition system requires external power (120VAC or 240VAC) and generates a pilot only when there is a call for heat.

Units come with a 3 foot, 3 prong power cord.

[raypack](https://www.raypak.com/product/above-ground-pool-spa-heater-156a/)